# Laravel update multiple rows

Tags: php, sql-update, laravel

I am a beginner with Laravel, and I'm stuck with my code.
I would like to store my site options and details in the database, and what I am stuck with I don't know how to update multiple rows, maybe my database structure is not the best either.

Database

```
id | option_name      | option_value
1  | site_name        | Website name
2  | site_slogen      | Website slogen
3  | site_description | Website description
4  | post_per_pages   | 20
```

My form

```
{{ Form::open('admin/options', 'POST', array('class' => 'span5 no-float centered')) }}

    @foreach($options as $option)

        <?php $name = str_replace('_', ' ', ucfirst($option->option_name)); ?>

        {{ Form::label($name, $name) }}
        @if($option->option_name == "site_description")
            {{ Form::textarea($option->option_name, $option->option_value, array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'rows' => '5')) }}
        @else
            {{ Form::text($option->option_name, $option->option_value, array('class' => 'input-block-level')) }}
        @endif

        {{ $errors->has($option->option_name) ? '<p class="val_error">' .$errors->first($option->option_name). '</p>' : '' }}

        {{ Form::hidden('id[]', $option->id) }}
    @endforeach

     {{ Form::button('Update options', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block')) }}
```

I know it's not the best, but I'm trying.
Could someone give me a hint with the multiple update?

I tried but I'm lost

Comment: update multiple rows.... ok. but what's the criteria to update? then the question ends up with multiple insert.... great!

Answer (score 3):

You could build a query, something like this:

```
YourTable::query()->where('YourTableColumn', 'Variable/Field to match against')->update(array('Fiel' => $new_username));
```

In Update you can pass array of fields with its value which you want to update for all fetched row.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i want to know it can affect the number of queries

```
$inputs = Input::all();

foreach($inputs as $key => $value)
{
    $content = Content::find($id);
    $content->$key = $value;
    $content->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate destination table, name it 'mytable_insertbypass', trunca before operation, then insert optimized, after insert, make a query to update:

UPDATE products, products_insertbypass 
SET products.price = products_insertbypass.price
WHERE products.id = products_insertbypass;

Favaloro rule's ;)

Answer (score -4):

You can loop through rows and save them.

```
$inputs = Input::all();
$content = Content::find($id);

foreach($inputs as $key => $value)
{
    $content->$key = $value;
}

$content->save();
```

Comment: thats wrong, you are updating multiple columns, not multiple rows.

Comment: that is updating columns in a single row